# Load The JSON From different links depending on whats going on in the app

Tags: ios, json, swift

What I'm trying to do is have my JSON loaded from different links (4 different links) depending on whats going on in my app. It's a radio network app with 4 different radio stations. I can push over what station is currently playing to my JSON ViewController but the problem is how do I get the JSON to do an "IF this current station is playing THEN pull from this link: LINK TO JSON INFO"? I know it's possible but don't know how to implement it. Here is my code for the JSON ViewController that I updated with a switch but no luck:

```
class TableViewController: UITableViewController {
//1. Create An Array To Store The SongData
var songs = [SongData]()
var currentStation: RadioStation!
var downloadTask: URLSessionDownloadTask?

override func viewDidLoad() { super.viewDidLoad()


    self.tableView.delegate = self
    self.tableView.dataSource = self

    //2. Load The JSON From The Main Bundle

    struct RadioStation {

        var name: String
        var streamURL: String
        var imageURL: String
        var desc: String
        var longDesc: String

        let currentStation = RadioStation!(name: String)
    var reqStr = ""
    switch currentStation {
    case "SPIN":
        reqStr = "http://streamdb3web.securenetsystems.net/player_status_update/JACKSON1_history.txt"
    case "The FUZE":
        reqStr = "http://streamdb3web.securenetsystems.net/player_status_update/JACKSON2_history.txt"
    case "The RANCH":
        reqStr = "http://streamdb3web.securenetsystems.net/player_status_update/JACKSON3_history.txt"
    case "SAGE":
        reqStr = "http://streamdb3web.securenetsystems.net/player_status_update/JACKSON4_history.txt"
    default:
        reqStr = "http://streamdb3web.securenetsystems.net/player_status_update/JACKSON1_history.txt"

  let urlText = URL (string: reqStr)

    do{
        //a. Get The Data From The From The File
        let data = try Data(contentsOf: urlText!)

        //b. Decode The Data To Our Structs
        let albumData = try JSONDecoder().decode(Response.self, from: data)

        //c. Append The Songs Array With The PlayHistory
        albumData.playHistory.song.forEach { songs.append($0) }

        //d. Test Some Data
        print("""
            **The First Album Details**
            Album = \(songs[0].album)
            Artist = \(songs[0].artist)
            Cover = \(songs[0].cover)
            Duration = \(songs[0].duration)
            Start = \(songs[0].programStartTS)
            Title = \(songs[0].title)
            """)

        //3. Load The Data
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }catch{

        print(error)
    }
        }
    }
}`
```

The code below is the original code before I updated it with the switch above.

```
    'class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

        //1. Create An Array To Store The SongData
        var songs = [SongData]()
        var currentStation: RadioStation!
        var downloadTask: URLSessionDownloadTask?

        override func viewDidLoad() { super.viewDidLoad()


            self.tableView.delegate = self
            self.tableView.dataSource = self

            //2. Load The JSON From The Main Bundle

            guard let urlText = URL (string: "http://streamdb3web.securenetsystems.net/player_status_update/JACKSON1_history.txt")
                else { return }


            do{
                //a. Get The Data From The From The File
                let data = try Data(contentsOf: urlText)

                //b. Decode The Data To Our Structs
                let albumData = try JSONDecoder().decode(Response.self, from: data)

                //c. Append The Songs Array With The PlayHistory
                albumData.playHistory.song.forEach { songs.append($0) }

                //d. Test Some Data
                print("""
                    **The First Album Details**
                    Album = \(songs[0].album)
                    Artist = \(songs[0].artist)
                    Cover = \(songs[0].cover)
                    Duration = \(songs[0].duration)
                    Start = \(songs[0].programStartTS)
                    Title = \(songs[0].title)
                    """)

                //3. Load The Data
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                }
            }catch{

                print(error)
            }

        }
```

Comment: it's recommended not to put this line -- let data = try Data(contentsOf: urlText) ---- in main queue

Comment: @Sh_Khan I know thats off the subject of the question but what is recommended then?

Comment: `Data(contentsOf:)` is a synchronous method designed to load data from __local__ URLs and not remote ones. Use `URLSession.dataTask` to load data from remote URLs.

Comment: You should make this statement inside a global queue and after you get content and parse it reload the table in mainQueue , beside your description of issue is misleading , what do you mean by **LINK TO JSON INFO** and what's if playing , i see http call , make the link dynamic if this is what you mean ??

Comment: @DávidPásztor  I replaced this line of code `let data = try Data(contentsOf: urlText)` with this line `let data = try URLSession.dataTask` and I get these errors now: Ambiguous use of 'dataTask' & No calls to throwing functions occur within 'try' expression. I'm very new to coding so please speak to me in simple terms, thanks.

Comment: @Sh_Khan My table is working fine and its pulling in all the data that is needed. My question is I need to be able to switch the JSON link to a different link when I change my station in the app. I have a way of telling this ViewController what station I'm on but don't know how to tell it to pull from a different link if a different station is currently playing. Make sense now?

Comment: you can make if statement to switch the url string according to the current station i mean if else / switch

Comment: @Sh_Khan I’m still very new to coding so can you be a little more informative please?